Cannot install plugins using Vundle and Git v1.8.3.1
I am running the :PluginInstall command with Vundle (Vim version 7.4) and attempts to run :PluginInstall will (try to) run a command like the following:
git clone --depth 1 --recursive --shallow-submodules 'https://github.com/adelarsq/vim-matchit.git' '/home/snrub/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/vim-matchit'

..., which returns the following error:
error: unknown option `shallow-submodules'
usage: [git clone usage message]

Assuming I can't upgrade Git (version 1.8.3.1) or Vim (version 7.4), how can I modify the "git clone" query in the Vundle source code to work with my old version?

This seems to be a Git question, not a Vim question. What about simply leaving out the --shallow-submodules option? The repo you want to clone from does not even have submodules.

Excellent. Removing the "shallow submodules" option appears to have fixed the problem. Thank you!

The question is about modifying Vundle code, so I’ve elected to leave it open for now.

Remove the "--shallow-submodules" option.
